# Why do Placeholders and Panels not show up in a recursive control search?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, recursion

I have a little recursive function I use now and then - which I want to re-use to show everything on a page, potentially hidden within placeholders/panels (and maybe at some point views)

```
Public Shared Sub ShowAllPanels(ByVal parent As Control)
    For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
        If c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            ShowAllPanels(c)
        Else
            Select Case (c.GetType().ToString())
                Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder"
                    CType(c, PlaceHolder).Visible = True
                Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel"
                    CType(c, Panel).Visible = True
                Case Else
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(c.GetType().ToString() + "")
            End Select
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

I am sure there is a more succinct way fo doing this, but I can't seem to poll my page and find the panels or placeholder.

I realise I could use a trycast - and get rid of any potential typo mistakes with the GetType - but debugging the types returned - nothing resembling a placeholder appears.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are checking if `c.Controls.Count > 0` which i think is true for the panel and the PlaceHolder. But in that case you just skip it and loop all child cotnrols.

So this should work:

```
Public Shared Sub ShowAllPanels(ByVal parent As Control)
    For Each c As Control In parent.Controls
        Select Case (c.GetType().ToString())
            Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder"
                CType(c, PlaceHolder).Visible = True
            Case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel"
                CType(c, Panel).Visible = True
            Case Else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(c.GetType().ToString() + "")
        End Select
        If c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            ShowAllPanels(c)
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

However, this generic method is shorter, more readabl and more reusable:

```
Public Shared Sub ShowControl(Of TCtrl As Control)(ByVal parent As Control, show As Boolean)
    Dim children = parent.Controls.OfType(Of TCtrl)()
    For Each child As TCtrl In children
        child.Visible = show
        ShowControl(Of TCtrl)(child, show)
    Next
End Sub
```

You use it in this way:

```
ShowControl(Of Panel)(Page, True)
ShowControl(Of PlaceHolder)(Page, True)
```